# Local database for mobile dictionary for J2ME

Tags: local, embedded-database

I'm now developing an English-to-Arabic phrase translator for a mobile phone for my final year project. I'm using the Eclipse (J2ME) IDE. However one of the requirements of my project is to use a local database. I was thinking I'd use MySQL since I have used it before. But this application also has to connect with a server. Thus, I have no idea what database is suitable for J2ME (exclude RDMS) for this project. Can anyone offer suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called an "embedded" database. Basically, it's a database that you access through a library, which  doesn't have a separate server component. SQLLite and MySQL Embedded are two examples. Since you're using Java, you might want to look into Apache Derby, which I believe ships with JDK 6.